# Искользование JS классов. Геттер для this или что-то такое

Tags: javascript, классы, объекты, перегрузка-операторов

Суть. У меня есть класс-надстройка для нативного canvas. Ниже чать его кода с конструктором.

```
class Canvas {
            constructor(id, height, width) {
                this.canvas  = document.getElementById(id);
                this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
                this.height  = height;
                this.width   = width;
                this.bbox    = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                this.max_hyp = Math.sqrt( this.width * this.width + this.height * this.height );
                this.max_phi = 360;
            }
}
```

Допустим, я создал объект этого класса.

```
let canvas = new Canvas("canvas", 500, 500);
```

И хочу, чтобы при клике по нему мышкой началось рисование, а при отпускание закончилось - это не проблема.

Проблема в проверке, которую мне приходится делать

```
function startDrawing(event) {
            if(event.target == canvas.canvas) {
...
}
```

Строчка

> canvas.canvas

меня убивает, но что можно с этим сделать? Ведь по сути идёт сравнение двух объектов DOM, а мой класс Canvas отображает немного другую сущность, но всё же хотелось бы чтобы при обращении к самому объекту класса или при сравнении мы обращались к this.canvas, а не к самому объекту.

Какой-нибудь перегрузки оператора сравнения мне бы хватило, но я не знаю, как...
Прошу помощи.

Comment: Нету перегрузок операторов в JS. Но вы можете в классе определить метод `equals` и сравнивать через него: `canvas.equals(event.target)`.

Comment: Конечно, можно использовать свой метод типа canvas.compare(obj), 
который вернёт this.canvas === obj.

Comment: Вот как интересно получилось, когда я свой коммент писал Вашего не было)

Comment: Ну да, пожалуй, это самый правильный вариант в данном случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы не сделать `startDrawing` методом самого класса надстройки? В примере ниже при нажатии на канвас будет запускаться метод `startDrawing`, который (для примера) просто выводит высоту самого канваса.

```js
class Canvas {
            constructor(id, height, width) {
                this.el  = document.getElementById(id);
                this.context = this.el.getContext('2d');
                this.height  = height;
                this.width   = width;
                this.bbox    = this.el.getBoundingClientRect();
                this.max_hyp = Math.sqrt( this.width * this.width + this.height * this.height );
                this.max_phi = 360;
                
                this.el.addEventListener("mousedown", () => this.startDrawing());
            }
            
            startDrawing() {
                console.log("Drawing on the canvas which height is " + this.height);
            }
}

let c = new Canvas("test", 600, 600);
```

```html
<canvas id="test"></canvas>
```

Если есть желание, регистрацию слушателя события можно осуществлять снаружи запуском отдельного метода, например `let c = new Canvas(); c.on("click", c.startDrawing)`. Только реализацию придется подправить, конечно.

Comment: Потому что я создаю еще другие объекты этого класса, на которых не предусматривается, но тем не менее, можно передавать функцию, которая будет вызываться при определенных условиях.

В целом, согласен, тоже хороший вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрБутареев тогда в вашем случае можно создать несколько дочерних классов (с использованием `extend`), которые будут расширять основной `Canvas`. И метод `startDrawing` у каждого из этих дочерних классов будет вызываться при определенных условиях.